Please explain the "Second theorem" of "Cantor's first set theory article"
I'm referring to this version of the wikipedia page (which was the latest version as of this writing): https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cantor%27s_first_set_theory_article&oldid=1206318255#Second_theorem
The sequence of real numbers i use is as follows:

The sequence starts with 0
Then it continues with all numbers in (0,1) that has exactly 1 decimal.
Then it continues with all numbers in (0,1) that has exactly 2 decimals and the last decimal is not 0 (because we already listed those numbers).
etc.

So it looks like this: 0, 0.1, 0.2, ..., 0.9, 0.01, 0.02, ..., 0.09, 0.11, 0.12, ..., 0.99, 0.001, ...
As i understand the proof, $a_1 = 0 = x_1$ and $b_1 = 0.1 = x_2$.
The first two numbers in my sequence that belong to (0, 0.1) are $a_2 = 0.01 = x_{11}$ and $b_2 = 0.02 = x_{12}$.
The first two numbers in my sequence that belong to (0.01, 0.02) are $a_3 = 0.011$ and $b_3 = 0.012$. I did not calculate the index of these in the sequence but i think it should be around 110.
If we continue, we see that both $a_n$ and $b_n$ approaches 0.011111....
So in the proof "Case 2" should apply which says:

Case 2: $a_∞ = b_∞$. Then $a_∞$ is not in the sequence since for all $n$: $a_∞$ is in the interval $(a_n, b_n)$ but $x_n$ does not belong to $(a_n, b_n)$. In symbols: $a_∞ ∈ (a_n, b_n)$ but $x_n ∉ (a_n, b_n)$.

Could you explain this please? $a_n$ and $b_n$ are the first two elements in the sequence that belong to the $(a_{n-1}, b_{n-1})$ interval. All previous elements of the sequence will obviously not belong this interval (because we chose the first two that did), and $x_n$ is just one of these "previous elements". So what does it prove that $x_n ∉ (a_n, b_n)$? Or did i misunderstand something?

Are you asking why $x_n \notin (a_n, b_n)$, or why this lets us conclude that $a_\infty$ is not in the sequence?

The proof goes like this.
You find a number $a_{\infty}$ - let's call it $c$, and now you have to prove that this number is not equal to any term of the sequence.
That is, for all $n :  x_n  \neq c  $
To prove this, you do: For each $n$, consider an interval $(a_n, b_n)$ such that $  x_n  ∉ (a_n, b_n)  $    but $c \in  (a_n, b_n)$
The proof that $  x_n  ∉ (a_n, b_n)  $ for that is given in the box between Case 2 and Case 3 on wikipedia, it should be easy for you to understand.
In this example, $c = 0.011111111111...$,  which belongs to  $(a_n, b_n)$ for each $n$ 
and you prove that : 
$x_1 \not\in (a_1, b_1)$ ; that is, $0 \not\in (0, 0.1)$ 
$x_2 \not\in (a_2, b_2)$ ; that is, $0.1 \not\in (0.01, 0.02)$ 
$x_3 \not\in (a_3, b_3)$ ; that is, $0.2 \not\in (0.011, 0.012)$ 
$\vdots$

Thanks, i think i get it now. Since the construction of $a_n$ and $b_n$ ensures that $x_n$ can never be in $(a_n, b_n)$ for my sequence, i feel it's a cheat.
